# Is $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $f(z) = z^2$ surjective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I know that, the map is surjective if

$$\forall b \in C, \exists a \in C \text{ such that } f(a) = b.$$

The problem I'm encountering is that normally I would try to find the $a$ by doing this
$$b = a^2 \text{ so } a = \sqrt{b}.$$
Then I would say:

$$f(x) = f(\sqrt{b}) = (\sqrt{b})^2 = b.$$

So $\forall b. \exists a \text{ such that } f(a) = b$.
But I was taught that I couldn't take the square root of an imaginary number. So I don't what to do...?

*PS: English is not the language I'm taught in, so I may have used the wrong words like 'map' or I may have used the terms the wrong way. In advance my apologies if I couldn't make myself clear.

Comment: It gets clearer if you write $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$.  Then a square root is just $\sqrt {|z|}e^{\frac {i\theta}{2}}$.

Comment: Take $w=r e^{i\phi}$ with $r>0$ and $z=\sqrt{r} e^{i\phi/2}$. Then $f(z)=w$, so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: When people say "you can't take the square root of a complex number" they mean that $\sqrt{\hphantom{-}}$ is not a _function_. It does not mean that there aren't square roots out there, but there are often two of them, and no nice, consistent way to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is surjective anyway as any $z$ can be written as $r(\cos \phi+i\sin\phi)$ with $r\ge 0$ and that is the square of (among others) $\sqrt r(\cos\frac\phi 2+i\sin\frac \phi2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Using $\sqrt{b}$ requires knowing it exists to begin with, which is essentially what you want to prove. (Actually a square root function on the complex number can only defined to a certain extent, but it's not relevant.)

If you already know De Moivre's formulas and the polar representation of complex numbers, it's easy. However it can also be done with the $x+iy$ representation. Given $a+ib\in \mathbb{C}$ (with $a$ and $b$ real), we want to find $x$ and $y$ real such that $(x+iy)^2=a+ib$.

Expanding the square and equating the real and imaginary parts, we get
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2=a \\[6px]
2xy=b
\end{cases}
$$
The case $b=0$ is the easiest: we must have $x=0$ or $y=0$. Looking at the first equation we get $x=\pm\sqrt{a}$ and $y=0$ if $a\ge0$; $x=0$ and $y=\pm\sqrt{-a}$ if $a<0$.

Note that $\sqrt{t}$ is well defined when $t$ is a nonnegative real number.

Suppose now $b\ne0$. Then we have $y=b/(2x)$ and the first equation gets transformed into
$$
4x^4-4ax^2-b^2=0
$$
The polynomial $4t^2-4at-b^2$ has a positive root, so we obtain
$$
x^2=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a}{2}
$$
from which we get two values for $x$ and the corresponding two values for $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $\alpha$ is in the image of $f$ if the polynomial $x^2 - \alpha$ has a solution. Well, the field $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, so this is the case.

Comment: An *essential* step in proving $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed is showing that $z\mapsto z^2$ is surjective. Well, unless you use Liouville's theorem.